# How do I test the security of the Salesforce site?

Tags: security

What is the best practice to test security?
In my case, I have a site with a database. Salesforce provides good data security of its users.
 So, in my Org, I have records (contacts, contact information, contact files and etc.)
Which tool I can use to test if I can check whether you can steal any user data if:
1) I am logged in by another user.
2) If I am not a user of the site

What else can I check for security?